# What should I do to maintain a long-distance relationship?

Tags: relationships

I am a 17 years old boy. On my last holiday I met a girl one year older than me. We talked for like 5 min and I really liked it. She is working in the hotel which I was guest in. We exchanged our facebook profiles because we wanted to maintain some sort of connection. For now we are only texting and sending photos. I know that it's not enough. The distance between me and her is 4-5 hours by car. Can you give me any advice on how to improve our realtionship? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi! Questions asking 'what should I do' or 'what can I do' tend to be very broad, and are also off-topic on this site. We can't decide for you what you should do to maintain your relationship. What do you mean by 'it's not enough'? What parts of your relationship are bad right now, and need improving? What would 'improve' be, what's the goal you're aiming towards? Would you qualify your relationship as romantic, or friendship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been in a long distance relationship for 5 years (my husband and I are married now, but still living apart due to immigration stuff).

What we found worked was making sure we made time for each other. We text, we make sure we talk to each other every day (like a phone call or Skype call or something), that sort of thing. Knowing that we will hear each other's voices, even for a bit (and see each others faces, if we do a video call) helps the distance seem shorter.

Other than that, find ways you can be together even with the kilometres between. For my husband and I, this means we play a lot of video games together, because that's what we like doing. There are sites you can use to watch the same movie together (or you get really good at going "okay press play in 3,2,1,go"),stuff like that.

Basically, it's like any other relationship, except you have to work a little harder to be present in each other's lives, because you can't just hang out in the same space when you want to. Make sure you make time to visit each other when you can, because nothing replaces that face to face time when you can actually touch each other and do "normal couple stuff" (you never realize how nice it is to just sit snuggled up to someone quietly reading or something until you can't do it).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help. But in my situation it is impossible to play video games together. She is not that type of person but I will find something else.